# How to extract the innerText of a <td> element with respect to the innerText of another <td> element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am using selenium in python. I have come across this table webelement. I need to check if a string is present in the webelement and return a corresponding string in case its present.

```
<table width="700px" class="tableListGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tableInfoTrBox">
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Task Code</th>
            <!-- th>Phone Number</th -->
            <th>Fota Job</th>
            <th colspan="2" class="thLineEnd">Task Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                         
        <tr class="tableTr_r">                                                                                      
            <td>2018-04-06 05:48:29</td>
            <td>FU</td>
            <!-- td></td -->
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:checkSchedule('57220180406-JSA69596727');">57220180406-JSA69596727</a>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:left;">
                                       updated from [A730FXXU1ARAB/A730FOJM1ARAB/A730FXXU1ARAB] to [A730FXXU2ARC9/A730FOJM2ARC1/A730FXXU2ARC9] 
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="btnTypeE">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <a href="#syncml" class="02320180406WSA84301933" onclick="showSyncML('IMEI352020090050529', '02320180406WSA84301933')">View</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>                                           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to search for "A730FXXU2ARC9/A730FOJM2ARC1/A730FXXU2ARC9" in this element and return "57220180406-JSA69596727" which is present in same row at a different place in the web page. Is it possible to do in selenium ?

EDIT: Cleaned the code to only contain useful data.

Comment: Update your HTML sample as it's not really readable. Share your current Python code as well

Comment: edited the code. I am given a part of string of one column and need to return the string in another column. 
I this case first string is "A730FXXU2ARC9/A730FOJM2ARC1/A730FXXU2ARC9"
and the expected output is  "57220180406-JSA69596727"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved by finding the element using the following Xpath:

```
//td[contains(., 'A730FXXU2ARC9/A730FOJM2ARC1/A730FXXU2ARC9')]/preceding-sibling::td[1]/a
```

Xpath can be read as

> *find `td` which contains "A730FXXU2ARC9/A730FOJM2ARC1/A730FXXU2ARC9". Then find the `td`
>   preceding the found `td` and move to the `a` tag*

After this you can get text using selenium

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//td[contains(., 'A730FXXU2ARC9/A730FOJM2ARC1/A730FXXU2ARC9')]/preceding-sibling::td[1]/a').text
```

Comment: little syntax error with quotes, but except that worked like a charm. Thanks man :D

Answer (score 0):

To look out for a text e.g.**A730FXXU2ARC9/A730FOJM2ARC1/A730FXXU2ARC9** and find out an associated text e.g. **57220180406-JSA69596727**, you can write a function as follows :

```
def test_me(myString):
        myText = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='tableListGrid']//tbody/tr[@class='tableTr_r']//td[.='" + myString + "']//preceding::td[1]/a").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Now, from your `main()`/`@Test` you can call the function with the desired text as follows :

```
test_me("A730FXXU2ARC9/A730FOJM2ARC1/A730FXXU2ARC9")
```